# How to Write a Mongo Query Where One of the Key Has a # Character as a Name in a Python / Flask Environment?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am a rookie to programming. I use Flask/Python as backend and MongoDB as my database. My mongo's documents are uploaded by CSV files and I have no control of the header name. Thus I cannot change the header's name to remove the # character.

```
**Mongo Collection**
Part #: "ABC123"
Description : "DC Motor 12V"

**Flask/Python/Backend**
query = { "Part #" : "ABC123" }
```

Since # character denotes comment in Python, I have tried to use **"Part \#"** to escape # but I think when it was sent to MongoDB as a query, it sees the backslash in the key name and no results appear.

I have googled for long time but unable to find a solution to it. Can someone provide a hint on what I can do? Thank you.

Comment: How are you querying? Are you using pymongo? From a quick test using pymongo myCol.find({"Part #" : "ABC123" }) it looks to work fine.

Comment: Yes. I am using pymongo.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Do you have any further information you can supply?

Answer (score 0):

After **@difurious** commented that there were no issue with query, I looked deeper.

Apparently the collection's field name "Part # " had a _ space after the hash. In Mongo's Compass DB, it doesn't shows up unless you click to edit it.

So it was not returning any result because of wrong field name.
To conclude this question, it was my mistake. # in a python string is acceptable for mongo query.

Thanks to **@difurious**